# KeyError: 'txs_date'

Tags: pandas, heroku, streamlit

I have an application that works fine in Heruko, i just refreshed my data, got an error when accessing the application:

```
KeyError: 'txs_date'

detail of the error as listed :
df['txs_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['txs_date'],format='%Y-%m-%d')
                                    ~~^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

this was working fine before last refresh, and it is working fine on streamlit platform

tried to find similar request in heruko and stackoverflow, no success

Comment: run following code : `df.get('txs_date', 'df dont have txs_date column')`  The return value will tell you the cause.

Comment: This is the Python function I'm using:@st.cache_data()
def load_villas():
    df = pd.read_csv(r'villas_period.csv',encoding=('utf_8'))
    df['txs_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['txs_date'],format='%Y-%m-%d')
    df['fst_day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['fst_day'])
    df['fst_qtr'] = pd.to_datetime(df['fst_qtr'])
    df.get('txs_date', 'df dont have txs_date column')
    return(df)